# Editor with textmate snippets support?

Tags: editor, code-snippets

I know of etexteditor and vim/emacs.

Are there any other windows editors which have textmate-like snippets support (eg. you write trigger word, press tab, it changes to something, you press tab again, and it changes to first stop, you can then enter something there and it will change on several other places according to snippet defined) ?
I know it's a little weird explanation, but you probably know what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

[InType](http://intype.info/home/index.php) could "someday" become what you're looking for, at least the alphas are promising. Sadly, a release version of InType is still far from being ready (see blog and forums).

**Update:** Currently, I'm using [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/), another great editor: fully Python-scriptable and snippets support.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [snipMate plugin for vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) - I use it and it works great

Answer (score 2):

[Redcar](http://redcareditor.com/), written in Ruby, was just released, but it's not polished by any means.

Apart from that, I don't know of any.

Answer (score 2):

[jEdit](http://www.jedit.org/) will do something similar if you use the [SuperAbbrevs](http://plugins.jedit.org/plugins/?SuperAbbrevs) plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio will do this, but it's nowhere near as nice as textmate / e.

Answer (score 2):

I don't use windows but whilst searching for a alternative for linux I came across  [e-texteditor](http://e-texteditor.com/).

Answer (score 2):

You can look into using an application independent of your IDE, to expand snippets.

I have a lorem ipsum snippet; one that contains my URL, my email, and so on, but you could also make snippets that contain code.

Applications: [Textexpander](http://lifehacker.com/software/text-substitution/download-of-the-day-texter-windows-242812.php) for Mac, [Typinator](http://www.macility.com/products/typinator/) for Mac, [Texter](http://lifehacker.com/software/text-substitution/download-of-the-day-texter-windows-242812.php) for Windows (no experience with the last one, so don't know if it's any good)

Answer (score 2):

Komodo Edit and Komodo IDE both support this, although TextMate is arguably a bit more refined and polished in this area. Komodo Edit is free, however, and compares very favorably against the likes of InType and E for Windows.

http://www.openkomodo.com/

Answer (score 0):

**Visual Studio 2015 since Update 2 RC**

> Visual Studio now supports consuming TextMate snippets with
>   IntelliSense completion by placing tmSnippet files into a snippet
>   folder.

https://t.co/kmG52wkOXe

**Visual Studio Code**

> Another addition to the yo code generator is the option to add
>   TextMate Snippets (.tmSnippets) to VS Code

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/user_ed/archive/2015/12/12/visual-studio-code-new-feature-yo-code-generator-textmate-snippets.aspx